# Cómo generar correctamente archivo en Java (mysql)

Tags: java, mysql

Intentando realizar una actividad me encuentro con el siguiente método:

-**generarArchivo**(String nombreArchivo, String pais) ----> generar un archivo de 
texto que contenga el listado de las oficinas del país pasado como segundo parámetro. 
El archivo debe tener el nombre pasado como primer parámetro. El separador de campos 
debe ser el punto y coma(;), el separador de registros el salto de línea. Deben guardarse 
todos los campos de la tabla Oficinas.

He probado de varias maneras con este método pero no logro sacarlo. La llamada desde el 
main no la muestro, solo el método generarArchivo que es mi principal duda. Muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Tabla oficinas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo de la clase GestionClassic:**

```
public class GestionClassic { 

    public static ResultSet consultar(String sql) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ConectarSingleton conexion = new ConectarSingleton();
        Connection con = ConectarSingleton.getConexion(); 

        PreparedStatement sentencia = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet resultados = sentencia.executeQuery();
        return resultados;

    }  

public static void generarArchivo (String nombreArchivo, String pais) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {

ConectarSingleton conexion=new ConectarSingleton();


Connection con = conexion.getConexion();

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(nombreArchivo);

Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

entrada.useDelimiter(";");  

        ResultSet rs = GestionClassic.consultar("select * from oficinas");
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+rs.getString(2)+rs.getString(3)+rs.getString(4)
            +rs.getString(5)+rs.getString(6)+rs.getString(7)+rs.getString(8)+rs.getString(9));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: En este código concatenas los campos sin ningún tipo de separador en la salida estándar (por pantalla). ¿Qué has intentado haciendo uso de `Scanner`? Si te das cuenta `useDelimiter()` se usa para delimitar campos al obtener datos de la corriente de datos (`System.in` o entrada estándar), no para sacarlos.

Comment: De acuerdo. Muy buena orientanción Óscar. Ahora lo único que me resulta extraño es que a pesar de que genere bien el archivo .txt, no muestra el listado de las oficinas segun el país que yo le paso en el main. He modificado la consulta y demás, pero sigue apareciendo en blanco el .txt ... ¿Alguna idea más?

Comment: ¿Con mi respuesta se ha generado el archivo? En ese caso marca la respuesta como correcta. El problema nuevo que tienes, ¿prodrías plantearlo en una nueva pregunta y poner allí el código? Deja un mensaje aquí cuando lo hagas y la miro.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187617/fallo-al-mostrar-listado-de-datos-en-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás sacando por salida estándar (`System.out.println`) la concatenación que has montado pero, además, no estás agregando ningún separador a los campos, de modo que "Nombre", "Apellido" y "Teléfono" se vería como "NombreApellidoTeléfono".

Además, estás intentado hacer uso de [`Scanner.useDelimiter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)) que sirve para separar datos de una corriente de datos de entrada, no de salida.

Una solución es enviar directamente esa cadena (correctamente separada por puntos y coma) a la instancia de `PrintWriter` que creaste haciendo uso [`PrintWriter.println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(java.lang.String)):

```
public static void generarArchivo(String nombreArchivo, String pais) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
    ConectarSingleton conexion = new ConectarSingleton();
    Connection con = conexion.getConexion();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(nombreArchivo);
    ResultSet rs = GestionClassic.consultar("SELECT * FROM oficinas");
    while(rs.next()) {
        pw.println(rs.getString(1) + ";"
            + rs.getString(2) + ";"
            + rs.getString(3) + ";"
            + rs.getString(4) + ";"
            + rs.getString(5) + ";"
            + rs.getString(6) + ";"
            + rs.getString(7) + ";"
            + rs.getString(8) + ";"
            + rs.getString(9)
        );
    }
}
```