# Fallo al mostrar listado de datos en Java

Tags: java, jdbc

En el siguiente método:

**generarArchivo(String nombreArchivo, String pais)**

Generar un archivo de texto que contenga el listado de las oficinas del país pasado como segundo parámetro. El archivo debe tener el nombre pasado como primer parámetro. El separador de campos debe ser el punto y coma(;), el separador de registros el salto de línea. Deben guardarse todos los campos de la tabla Oficinas.

Me genera correctamente el archivo `nombreArchivo.txt` tal y como vemos a continuación en el main, solo que en él no escribe el listado de las oficinas del país que le indico en el segundo parámetro, en este caso, por ejemplo, "USA". Imprimiendo en pantalla lo hace correctamente (muestro captura); pero yo quiero que me genere el mismo listado en el `.txt` y no lo hace. ¿A qué puede deberse?

***Método de la clase que lo muestra por pantalla bien:***

```
public static void generarArchivo(String nombreArchivo, String pais) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
        ConectarSingleton conexion=new ConectarSingleton();
        Connection con = conexion.getConexion();

        ResultSet rs = GestionClassic.consultar("select * from oficinas where pais ='"+pais+"'");
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+";"+rs.getString(2)+";"+rs.getString(3)+";"+rs.getString(4)+";"
            +rs.getString(5)+";"+rs.getString(6)+";"+rs.getString(7)+";"+rs.getString(8)+";"+rs.getString(9));

        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Método de la clase que no escribe datos en el archivo:***

```
public static void generarArchivo(String nombreArchivo, String pais) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
        ConectarSingleton conexion=new ConectarSingleton();
        Connection con = conexion.getConexion();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(nombreArchivo);

        ResultSet rs = GestionClassic.consultar("select * from oficinas where pais ='"+pais+"'");
        while(rs.next()) {
            pw.println(rs.getString(1)+";"+rs.getString(2)+";"+rs.getString(3)+";"+rs.getString(4)+";"
            +rs.getString(5)+";"+rs.getString(6)+";"+rs.getString(7)+";"+rs.getString(8)+";"+rs.getString(9));

        }
    }
```

***main:***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 try {  

GestionClassic.generarArchivo("nombreArchivo.txt", "USA");

        } catch (SQLException  | ClassNotFoundException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Por un lado te recomiendo que uses consultas preparadas y no concatenación de cadenas para montar el SQL. Por otro lado, ¿Podrías poner el código que has usado para generar la salida de la captura de pantalla? ¿Has probado a cerrar el archivo explícitamente con [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close())?

Comment: Veo que has cambiado `pw` por `System.out.println`. Voy a editar la pregunta para dejar ambos códigos para no crear confusión a otros compañeros.

Comment: De acuerdo Óscar. Siento ciertas confusiones, llevo poco tiempo en esto. Ya con el pw.close() parece que todo va bien e incluye las oficinas en el archivo. Muchas gracias por toda la atención mostrada. Un saludo.

Comment: De nada. Puedes responderte a ti mismo con lo que has hecho para arreglar el problema, te cedo la reputación de la respuesta :)

Comment: Debes redactar una respuesta, no modificar la pregunta con la respuesta. Si mañana no la has redactado lo haré yo con enlaces, explicación y uso de consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Datos perdidos en el archivo

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.lang.String)), al igual que [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.lang.String)), no vuelca el contenido del búfer a la corriente de datos de manera automática si no se activa en algunos de los métodos del constructor, por lo que podrían quedarse datos sin enviar (en este caso, sin escribir en el archivo).

Pongamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class Prueba {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("prueba.txt");
      pw.println("hola");
    } catch (Exception e) { }
  }
}
```

Al ejecutarlo el archivo quedaría vacío.

Para solucionarlo tienes tres posibilidades:

- Forzar la escritura haciendo uso de `flush()` o `close()`.
- Activar el volcado automático de datos tras un `print()` o `println()` usando un constructor que lo permita.

#### Forzar escritura explícita con [`flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush())

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class Prueba {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("prueba.txt");
      pw.println("hola");
      pw.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
  }
}
```

#### Cerrar el archivo con [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close())

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class Prueba {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("prueba.txt");
      pw.println("hola");
      pw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
  }
}
```

#### Volcado automático con el constructor [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean))

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
public class Prueba {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("prueba.txt"), true);
      pw.println("hola");
      pw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
  }
}
```

---

### Consultas preparadas

No deberías concatenar cadenas a una consulta SQL. Podrías tener problemas si la variable contiene comillas simples (por ejemplo, que el parámetro `pais` valga `Salem's Lot`).

Para solucionarlo debes usar [consultas preparadas JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) sobrecargando de la siguiente manera [el método `consultar()` de tu anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187423/c%C3%B3mo-generar-correctamente-archivo-en-java-mysql):

```
public static ResultSet consultar(
  String sql,
  String parametro1
) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
  ConectarSingleton conexion = new ConectarSingleton();
  Connection con = ConectarSingleton.getConexion(); 
  /* Preparamos la consulta */
  PreparedStatement sentencia = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  /* Asignamos al primer ? el valor de parametro1 */
  sentencia.setString(1, parametro1);
  /* Ejecutamos la consulta como de costumbre */
  ResultSet resultados = sentencia.executeQuery();
  return resultados;
}  

public static void generarArchivo(
  String nombreArchivo,
  String pais
) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
  ConectarSingleton conexion = new ConectarSingleton();
  Connection con = conexion.getConexion();
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(nombreArchivo);

  /* Llamamos al nuevo método indicando el primer parámetro: "pais" */
  ResultSet rs = GestionClassic.consultar(
    "SELECT * FROM oficinas WHERE pais = ?",
    pais
  );
  while(rs.next()) {
    pw.println(
      rs.getString(1) + ";"
      + rs.getString(2) + ";"
      + rs.getString(3) + ";"
      + rs.getString(4) + ";"
      + rs.getString(5) + ";"
      + rs.getString(6) + ";"
      + rs.getString(7) + ";"
      + rs.getString(8) + ";"
      + rs.getString(9)
    );
  }
}
```

De esta manera, cuando indiques un parámetro se ejecutará ese método que tiene un parámetro adicional de tipo `String`, asignando al primer `?` su valor de manera correcta sin problemas con comillas simples `'` y protegiendo tu código contra los [nefastos efectos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) de la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).